# Google Sign In package's disconnect method call results in error when trying to sign in again using Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-android

I am using Firebase auth with Flutter and have implemented google sign in using google_sign_in package version ^5.2.3
I noticed that after signing out, when I clicked sign in again the app didn't prompt me to select which of my google accounts I want to sign in it, instead logging me in with the previous account I had used.

After some research I added the following code in sign out flow

```
await GoogleSignIn().disconnect();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

I was able to sign out, but when I tried to log in again, I got an exception with following message

> PlatformException (PlatformException(exception, BAD_REQUEST, null, null))

HOWEVER, if I hot restart app, I am able to sign in and also get the prompt to select a google account I want to log in. The google sign in plugin github doesn't allow issue filing so I can't get help here. Help appreciated.

flutter doctor

> $ flutter doctor
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√]
> Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.18362.535], locale en-US)
>
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.0-rc2)
>
> ```
> X cmdline-tools component is missing
>
>   Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
>
>   See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
>
> X Android license status unknown.
>   Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
>   See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for
> ```
>
> more details.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
>
> [√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
>
> [!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2016.2)
>
> ```
> X This install is older than the minimum recommended version of 2017.1.0.
> ```
>
> [√] VS Code, 32-bit edition (version 1.63.2)
>
> [√] Connected device (2 available)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Answer (score 1):

I leave the answer as a reference for another person who has the same error.

```
     await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
```

Implementation though icon button:

```
 IconButton(
            onPressed: (() async {
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
            await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
          }),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app)
           )
```